# Single flow and Multi flow in AWS placement group

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, cloud

As per specification's of the placement group in AWS, EC2 instance can utilize 10Gbps in single flow and 20Gbps in multi flow.

What does this **single flow** and **multi flow** traffic signify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to AWS Documentation,

> For instances that are enabled for enhanced networking, traffic between instances within the same Region that is addressed using IPv4 or IPv6 addresses can use up to 5 Gbps for single-flow traffic and up to 25 Gbps for multi-flow traffic. A flow represents a single, point-to-point network connection.

That means single flow is a single connection which can use network bandwidth upto 5 Gbps while multi-flow means parallel different connections which can take upto 25 Gbps of bandwidth in total.